# Can not load R Java package

Tags: java, r, java-9, rjava

I tried every solution on the internet to resolve the issue but it did not work.

Firstly, this is the java version.

```
$ java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

I tried

`sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

But this also did not work.

So the only solution that works is typing:

```
 dyn.load(paste0(system2('/usr/libexec/java_home', stdout = TRUE), '/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'))
```

However I don't want to type that every time I open RStudio. So what else I can try? Does anybody have an idea?

I am suspecting that the problem may be occurring due to the fact that I am using MacOS High Sierra and java version '9.0.4'.

Thanks to the comment below I tried to reverting a previous version of java using

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

So that I have

```
    java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

But the problem is not resolved.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the Mehul Katara's post I removed java 9 and installed 8. However this was also not sufficient for `sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib` to do the job. So what I did is I go to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and deleted the file  jdk9 by hand.

Comment: Downgrade to java 8 it will work. Recently new java 9 not working with rjava. Wait for rjava developer update that package.

Comment: I have tried it but unfortunately it did not help either.

Comment: Which r java package you want to install ? I'm using rJava in java 8 and working fine.

Comment: I am trying to use xlsx package in R which requires rJava package. The weird thing is I have tried the sudo ln ... code in another pc and that worked for it as well. I am about to go crazy.

Comment: I am using Rjava because xlsx required it. Try to complete remove java 9 and restart pc and install java 8. I will work.

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: It would be interesting to investigate the original issue in more detail. Your ln command includes a path with the "jre" directory which does not exist so maybe that is part of the issue.

Comment: Hello Alan, What do you mean by " 'jre' directory which does not exist " ? When I copy and paste that address to the finder (using "Go to Folder") I actually go to the directory.